# Japnese letter is not showing in hyperlink and anchor of my multilanguage website using resource file?

Tags: asp.net, resx, multilingual

I have used it in masterpage.

```
<div class="menu_nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx">hello</asp:HyperLink>
    </li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx"><span>
      <asp:Label ID="lblAboutUs" runat="server" Text="About Us"></asp:Label></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I have used this code:

```
ResourceManager rm;
    CultureInfo ci;
    private void LoadString(CultureInfo ci)
    {

        lblCompanyName.Text = rm.GetString("siteName", ci);
        lblSlogan.Text = rm.GetString("siteSlogan", ci);

        lblAboutUs.Text = rm.GetString("menuAboutUs", ci);
        HyperLink1.Text = rm.GetString("menuHome", ci);}
     if (Session["cultureID"] =="1")
        {


            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Strings",
                     System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
            ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            LoadString(ci);}
        else if( Session["cultureID"] =="2")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
            rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Strings",
                     System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
            ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            LoadString(ci); }
```

All thing is fine in label (I have used label to show website Name) only but when I use hyperlink or label inside the anchor `<a href>` to make menu, The Japanese language is not shown (English letter is fine). If I look in page source (in browser), the Japanese language is shown. The problem is that the Japanese data from resx is not rendering on my page. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it is working for me. There could be a problem in the Web page. try add this  tag in your  section of the page. It would render the Japanese chars perfectly.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Comment: Yeah ... It's been long time since I posted this question. But I believed that i had used that tag.

Comment: @YogendraPaudyal You can mark it as answer, so that it could be helpful for others.